# gpg: passwordless decryption works in terminal, but not in tmux based msmtp/mutt (can't open /dev/tty)

Tags: mutt, gpg, smtp

### first try: (with --no-tty in my msmtp config)

- (reboot)
- head -n 1 ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf

  use-agent
- gpg agent is started:

  % systemctl --user status gpg-agent.service 
   gpg-agent.service - GnuPG private key agent 
   Loaded: loaded (/home/toogley/.dotfiles/systemd/user/gpg-agent.service; enabled) 
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2015-12-30 17:42:31 CET; 23s ago
   Process: 1290 ExecStart=/usr/bin/gpg-agent --daemon --homedir=%h/.gnupg (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
   Main PID: 1295 (gpg-agent) 
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/gpg-agent.service
   └─1295 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --daemon --homedir=/home/toogley

/.gnupg

- Password *with* in devMailPW.asc: gpg -e -a -r $(my email adress)
- it doesn't change anything, if i put a \n after the PW, as suggested here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GPG#Encrypt_and_decrypt
- gpg -d devMail.asc ==> spawns dialog to enter PW for the first time
- afterwards gpg -d devMail.asc doesn't require me to enter my PW
- sending a mail with mutt results in:

  gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
  gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input
  msmtp: cannot read output of 'gpg -d --no-tty /home/toogley/.dotfiles/mutt/accounts/devMailPW.asc'
- the relevant part in my muttrc:

  set sendmail="msmtp --file=/home/toogley/.dotfiles/mutt/accounts/dev.smtp"
- my dev.smtp:

  passwordeval "gpg -d --no-tty /home/toogley/.dotfiles/mutt/accounts/devMailPW.asc"

### second try: (without --no-tty in my msmtp config)

- (same as before)
- sending a mail with mutt results in:

  gpg: cannot open tty `/dev/tty': No such device or address
  msmtp: cannot read output of 'gpg -d 
  +/home/toogley/.dotfiles/mutt/accounts/devMailPW.asc'

### third try: (with --batch)

- (same as before)
- (% gpg -d --batch devMailPW.asc works properly)
- sending a mail with mutt results in:

  gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
  gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
  gpg: Invalid passphrase; please try again ...
  gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
  gpg: Invalid passphrase; please try again ...
  gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
  gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 3970B3E5, created 2015-12-28
        ""
  gpg: public key decryption failed: bad passphrase
  gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available
  msmtp: cannot read output of 'gpg -d --batch
  +/home/toogley/.dotfiles/mutt/accounts/devMailPW.asc'

**EDIT** tmux plays an essential role in that situation.

=> the first and third approach works outside of my tmux environment. it spawns even for my password and asks for it. (which is great)

Comment: Do you start `tmux` before or after you start the gpg agent?

Comment: The tests were made with starting the tmux session after the gpg agent

Comment: What happens if you start the GPG agent inside the `tmux` session? It may be that the new shell inside `tmux` can't talk tot he agent running outside that shell.